# how to sort multiple columns in an order in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Data Frame:

```
        A   B   C
    0   a   c0  170
    1   b   c0  170
    2   c   c0  88
    3   d   c1  12
    4   e   c1  28
    5   f   c2  160
    6   g   c2  37
    7   h   c1  12
    8   i   c2  160
    9   j   c0  88
```

and I required to first sort it by column A (alphabetic order), then column C (descending order) and then column B (alphabetic order). The output should look like this:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   c0  170
1   b   c0  170
2   c   c0  88
3   j   c0  88
4   e   c1  28
5   d   c1  12
6   h   c1  12
7   f   c2  160
8   i   c2  160
9   g   c2  37
```

I am not able to do it using sort_values, even tho using multiple times. I tried the following:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["A"], ascending=True)\
            .sort_values(by=["C"], ascending=False)\
            .sort_values(by=["B"], ascending=True)\
            .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I'm getting the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working if sorting in one `sort_values` method:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["A", "C", 'B'], ascending=[True, False, True], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   A   B    C
0  a  c0  170
1  b  c0  170
2  c  c0   88
3  d  c1   12
4  e  c1   28
5  f  c2  160
6  g  c2   37
7  h  c1   12
8  i  c2  160
9  j  c0   88
```

If change order of sorting ouput is correct:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["B", "C", 'A'], ascending=[True, False, True], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   A   B    C
0  a  c0  170
1  b  c0  170
2  c  c0   88
3  j  c0   88
4  e  c1   28
5  d  c1   12
6  h  c1   12
7  f  c2  160
8  i  c2  160
9  g  c2   37
```

Comment: Almost there, the problem is index(7,8,9) are not correct. column B should be first c0, c1 and then c2.

Comment: @RafaelFerreira - So it means need sorting by `B`, then by `C` and last by `A` ?